# Where to store custom module unit test in a project used by Ansible Tower?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-tower

I finished coding three Ansible custom module that are stored in a Git Repository that is used by a Ansible Tower Project.
The directory tree looks like that :

```
> files/
>   - a.txt
>   - b.txt
> library/
>   - common_code.py
> module_utils/
>   - custom_module1.py
>   - custom_module2.py
> templates/
>   - c.txt.j2
>   - d.txt.j2
> playbook.yml
```

I couldn't find anywhere where I should store the custom module unit tests, or even the module_utils unit test ? Right next to the py files ? What is the best pratice ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I went on a more traditional way by adding a tests directory and multiple `__init__.py` files :

```
> files/
>   - a.txt
>   - b.txt
> library/
>   - __init__.py
>   - common_code.py
> module_utils/
>   - __init__.py
>   - custom_module1.py
>   - custom_module2.py
> templates/
>   - c.txt.j2
>   - d.txt.j2
> tests/
>   - __init__.py
>   - test_custom_module1.py
>   - test_custom_module2.py
>   - test_common_code.py
> playbook.yml
```

and imported the other files to test in the units tests like this :

```
from module_utils.custom_module1 import *
from module_utils.custom_module2 import *
from library.common_code import *
```

I had to modify the import in the custom modules :

```
try:
    from ansible.module_utils.common_code import util
except ImportError: # We except an ImportError in unit tests so we import it differently :D
    from module_utils.common_code import util
```

And added some specific Exception to handle the exit_json and fail_json as stated [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing_units_modules.html#ensuring-failure-cases-are-visible-with-mock-objects) like this :

```
self.module = MagicMock()
self.module.exit_json.side_effect = AnsibleExitJson(Exception)
self.module.fail_json.side_effect = AnsibleFailJson(Exception)
```

and later in a unit test function

```
self.module.fail_json.assert_called()
self.module.exit_json.assert_not_called()
```